# How to write ${variable} value with Put String To Cell Keyword

Tags: robotframework

```
${url}= Selenium2Library.GetLocation
Put String to Cell Test 1 0 ${url}
```

Is this Right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have at least two spaces between a keyword and each argument. I don't know anything about `Put String TO Cell`, but assuming all of the text following it are separate arguments, it should be something like this:

```
Put String to Cell  Test  1  0  ${url}
```